# luks single signon

Tags: linux, authentication, luks

I've got [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) (Linux Unified Key Setup) running on a couple of my Linux boxes.  I've looked online but haven't seen anyone document how to make it work in a single signon option, but was hoping someone could either point me in the right direction or give a definitive no that won't work (or more likely, no that won't work without writing some extra PAM etc. code).

Specifically, what I would like to do is boot up my system (which has let's assume 4 user accounts).  When I get prompted for my passphrase, it unlocks LUKS and boots up, and then tries that same passphrase to log in the user that's associated with that passphrase.  (LUKS supports 8 different passphrases but I'd be fine if there was just a single user supported (my primary username) and if I wanted to log in to a different account, I could log out / switch user.

Update: I'm encrypting the whole disk.

Comment: Sounds like you're simply looking for a way to make that user autologin (and ignore the LUKS part completely). `cryptsetup` doesn't really give any feedback as to which passphrase slot was being used in the unlocking. Either way you'd have to script this manually.

Comment: Is the entire drive encrypted, or just the home? If it's just the home you can use pam_mount for this.

Comment: @Patrick doing whole disk encryption; I'm assuming pam_mount would work in the other order (I login, and that triggers unlocking my home directory?)

Comment: Correct. And with whole drive encryption, what frostschutz said is correct, you'll have to write a script (and it'd likely be very difficult to do securely).